# how to remove icon from dailymotion player sdk in android

Tags: android, video, dailymotion-api

I'm developing an application in which i'm using dailymotion player sdk from https://github.com/dailymotion/dailymotion-player-sdk-android. I want to remove [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlkCA.png) icon.

It will be helpful if anyone can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I also tried that with no luck.
I followed following approach

```
    Map<String, String> playerParams = new HashMap<>();
    defaultQueryParameters.put("ui-logo","false");
    defaultQueryParameters.put("ui-start-screen-info","false");
    mVideoView.load(videoDetails.getId(), playerParams);
```

It doesn't work so I took out PlayerWebView.java file and added it to my code and added following to build.gradle

```
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.5.1'
```

And then changed my xml

```
    <com.dailymotion.android.player.sdk.PlayerWebView
      android:id="@+id/dm_player_web_view"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="215dp">
    </com.dailymotion.android.player.sdk.PlayerWebView>
```

to

```
    com.example.web.PlayerWebView
```

and made following changes in file PlayerWebView.java

```
    public void load(String videoId, Map<String, String> params) {
    if (!mIsInitialized) {
        Map<String, String> defaultQueryParameters = new HashMap<>();
        defaultQueryParameters.put("sharing-enable", "false");
        defaultQueryParameters.put("watchlater-enable", "false");
        defaultQueryParameters.put("like-enable", "false");
        defaultQueryParameters.put("collections-enable", "false");
        defaultQueryParameters.put("fullscreen-action", "trigger_event");
        defaultQueryParameters.put("locale", Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());


        defaultQueryParameters.put("ui-logo","false");
        defaultQueryParameters.put("ui-start-screen-info","false");

        initialize("https://www.dailymotion.com/embed/", defaultQueryParameters, new HashMap<String, String>());
    }
    queueCommand(COMMAND_LOAD, videoId, params);
}
```

Now it works like charm

Comment: Thank you very much i m sucvcessfully removed this icon from player thanks lot sir......

Comment: is there a way to remove related videos after competion of video?
[link](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-klgCbt4QLbk/WoPU9w10EKI/AAAAAAAABo4/vyrCKpd7f4AHa05YsIV45eiBLDWPuGTjQCL0BGAYYCw/h480/2265578780940211746%253Faccount_id%253D0)

again thanks for above answer sir